# VSPackage Builder search dialogue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vs-extensibility, vspackage

I'd like to add a search dialogue popup, really just a text box or something at the top right of the current document.  I've messed around with the VSPackage builder and it's easy enough, but I'm having trouble finding out which UI elements I should be looking at.

A ToolWindow doesn't quite fit I don't think -- I'd like what I'm doing to be borderless.  I tried just using a custom WPF window by itself but that doesn't play well with the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds what you're after is an editor viewport adornment.

This is a type of extension that has a class inherited from `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.IWpfTextViewCreationListener`

To create an adornment, you can use the **Editor Viewport Adornment** project template under *Visual C#\Extensibility*.

Try this example:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55196/Code-InfoBox-Visual-Studio-Extension-VSX-2010

Comment: This does seem like the right solution, but I haven't had time to actually get into trying it out.